# Replacing Strings using Maven in Java Annotations

Tags: java, maven, annotations

I am trying to replace a String in a Java annotation with variables from my pom.xml.

The pom.xml currently contains:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <parent.version>101</parent.version>
</properties>
```

I am trying to have the ${parent.version} replace in the annotation below to avoid having to replace the value multiple times as it is dependent on other versions

```
public class MyClass {
  @Version { 
    parent = "${parent.version}"
  } 
  //more code to which cannot be moved elsewhere nor is really a template
}
```

I have looked at some replacement plugins, however they have either failed or require changing the source folder which feels to me unacceptable in sharing the project.

Is there such a method which can replace this ${parent.version} however not use a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, you probably want to use the [templating-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/).

Comment: According to it, it says that "Please note that filtering the standard src/main/java folder is not supported.", which was something to which I would prefer. This just seems to require adding some template folder, which I explained would not work here.

Comment: Both `src/main/java` and `target/generated-sources/java-templates` are compiled at the same time. And your IDE can perfectly add this folder to the list of sourcefolders. Give it a try, just follow the instructions of `how to use filtering`, there's really nothing more you need to do.

Comment: Templates are templates. It is a logically bad idea to put fully executing code into a template since it is not a template. While it works, it is not really "ideal" in a sharing enviroment since it is a source, not a template. Just because it is being compiled does not mean it makes sense to put it there. While it works, I would prefer not to have to do it that way.

Comment: Your question was for a solution for annotations, and the suggested solution the best when following "The Maven Way(tm)". In fact, I wouldn't use an annotation to get the version. Instead I would read it from a `resource` on the classpath.

Comment: I would not want to use annotations either, however this is required for an API, which I detest how they required this. I found a way to go about it though using the antrun since I could not get templating-maven to correctly compile the project, but that might have been my fault